# VB.NET join datatables - LINQ error in output

Tags: vb.net, linq, powershell, datatable

tearing my hair out... I've read nearly all topics on joining datatables (mostly using LINQ)but still can't output a join result to a datatable/datagridview

dt_alluserrequests' columns: **Application,User, CurrentState, Comments, LastModifiedDate**
dt_myusers' columns: **samaccountname, displayname, physicaldeliveryofficename, mail, telephonenumber**

dt_allrequests comes from Powershell, dt_myusers comes from AD

the result shows a table structure in the dgv with errors as column titles and empty rows.

```
 Try
        Dim dt_reqs_icansee = From a In dt_allrequests.AsEnumerable() _
                              Join b In dt_myusers.AsEnumerable() _
                              On a.Field(Of String)("User") Equals b.Field(Of String)("samaccountname")
                              Select a

        dgv_requests.DataSource = dt_reqs_icansee.ToList
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Exit Sub
```

any help appreciated.
thanks
Kris

Answer (score 0):

In joins you need to have `select new { a, b }`

Take a look at:
[How to use LINQ to join multiple DataTables](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecb6a83d-b9b0-4e64-8107-1ca8757fe58c/how-to-use-linq-to-join-multiple-datatables?forum=adodotnetdataset)